# How to make classes scroll position dependent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a better way to do this as I use static numbers [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/zed-magdy/pen/jONrZLw)

```js
var div = $('.fclass');
var par = $('.sclass');
const pos = par.position().top;
$(window).on('scroll',()=>{
  if((par.position().top - pos) > -76){
    div.removeClass('fixed');
  }
  if((par.position().top - pos) == 18){
    div.addClass('fixed');
  }

});
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="fclass fixed">
    the first div
</div>
<div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
<p class="sclass sticky">
    the second paragraph
</p>
<div style="height: 1000px;"></div>
```

Comment: I feel like this question might be a better asked over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no need for js scroll event at all .. good Html structure and css Sticky can do that for you

```css
.paragraph{
  height : 1000px;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background : red;
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<!-- Paragraphs holds paragraphs -->
<div class="paragraphs">

  <!-- First paragraph -->
  <div class="paragraph">
    <h1 class="paragraph-head sticky">First Paragraph</h1>
    <div class="paragraph-content">
      First paragraph content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Second paragraph -->
  <div class="paragraph">
    <h1 class="paragraph-head sticky">Second Paragraph</h1>
    <div class="paragraph-content">
      Second paragraph content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Third paragraph -->
  <div class="paragraph">
    <h1 class="paragraph-head sticky">Third Paragraph</h1>
    <div class="paragraph-content">
      Third paragraph content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```